# Why is the Viewport rendering completely different from the Camera rendering (Cycle, Transparent material with refraction)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, camera, transparency

I have a simple scene with an "Image as plane" and a full transmission "hyperbolic lens" looking at it (scene built from the indications given at https://arachnoid.com/blender_graphics/index.html).

When I look at the viewport, I get a nice rendering (cycle progressive view mode).

[image: Viewport rendering]

When I ask for a camera rendering I get a strange sphere in the middle of the rendering, with a very strong magnification.

[image]

Any idea of what causes this discrepency? I would like to have a rendering w/o this artefact (if it's one).

Comment: In the inspector click the icon of the filter or funnel and enable the option that looks like a camera and the one that looks like a screen to the left of the camera - are there any objects with camera on but are hidden? or on in the camera but off with the screen?

alternatively is there a modifier that is different in the viewport vs render?

Comment: Congratulations. I had 2 alternate lenses I played with (a spherical and an hyperbolic one with a different curvature) that were both hidden but not deactivated for rendering. Gosh. I should have thought about this. Thanks a lot !!!!

Comment: happy to help. since it worked for you i will make it an answer so that other people will find it

Answer (score 0):

in the inspector click icon of the filter or funnel

[image]

and enable the option that looks like a camera and the one that looks like a screen to the left of the camera

[image]

[image]

are there any objects with camera on but are hidden? or on in the camera but off with the screen?

[image]

alternatively is there a modifier that is different in the viewport vs render?
[image]